# How to recognize a color in a specific area with opencv and control an output on Raspberry with it?

Tags: python, opencv

For school we have a project with vision, only I can do a bit of programming, but I am not very familiar with opencv yet. My question is, in short, is it possible if a color black comes in a specific area of ​​the camera that I can, for example, light an LED or send an output high with the raspberry pi. The advantage is that the live image of a white paper with black circle. When the paper shifts and the black circle comes in a specific area of the image, an output of the raspberry must be sent high. I know how to recognize a circle or square in opencv only recognize a color in a specific area and then send a led high I can't find much information about it on the internet. Hopefully you can help me with an example code or help me get the information. If you only know how to recognize the color black comes in a specific area of ​​the camera and use if statement where I can put code that will help a lot also. thank you in advance.

I use the Raspberry Pi 4 with opencv 4.5.1 and Python 3.7.3

I have made a image of the videocapture
[visualization of the videocapture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pDya3.png)
I also took a screenshot of how the code should work. Unfortunately the code is not really working yet because I added the text myself. [color detected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gv6fq.jpg)
[color not detected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NW4p0.jpg)

```
import cv2
#from gpiozero import LED
print("packege Imported")

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cap.set(3, 640)
cap.set(4, 480)

font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX

IM_WIDTH = 640
IM_HEIGHT = 480

TL_Zone1 = (int(IM_WIDTH*0.2),int(IM_HEIGHT*0.4))
BR_Zone1 = (int(IM_WIDTH*0.3),int(IM_HEIGHT*0.6))

xmin, ymin = TL_Zone1
xmax, ymax = BR_Zone1

#led1 = LED(2)

def colorDetection(img):
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 15, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
    contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    img = cv2.drawContours(img, contours, -1, (0, 0, 255), 3)

    if #there is a few black pixels in the area then
        cv2.putText(img, "color detected",(TL_Zone1[0] + 10, TL_Zone1[1] - 10), font, 1, (0, 0, 255), 3, cv2.LINE_AA)
        #led1.on()
    else:
        cv2.putText(img, "color not detected",(TL_Zone1[0] + 10, TL_Zone1[1] - 10), font, 1, (0, 0, 255), 3, cv2.LINE_AA)
        #led1.off()

while True:
    success, img = cap.read()
    imgDetection = img.copy()

    colorDetection(imgDetection)

    cv2.rectangle(imgDetection, TL_Zone1, BR_Zone1, (0, 0, 255), 8)

    cv2.imshow("Video", img)
    cv2.imshow("Detection", imgDetection)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
```

Comment: Black is not really an ideal colour for your circle - you will get that when the lights are off too... or when someone leaves the lens cap on... or walks in front of the camera :-)

Comment: I understand what you are saying, but unfortunately I cannot choose the color. because it must be black.

Comment: why are you using a Canny filter? that detects the edges, so it's not needed for your purposes as it discards all color information.

Comment: @dzang I have used and adapted the code from a previous project of my own. I was not sure why I still had that in there, but I have updated that.

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume that your image is `im` and that your area of interest is a rectangle defined by `[row_min, row_max, col_min, col_max]`. An image is stored as an array of dimensions: `[rows, cols, channels]` where `channels == 3` as they are the RGB channels.

Black is usually defined by low values in all 3 channels, so for example, the expressions:

```
im[row_min:row_max, col_min:col_max, :].reshape(-1).sum()
```

represents the total intensity in your aoi. `reshape(-1)` transforms the selected portion of the array in a 1D array and then you can sum all values to get the total intensity in all channels with `.sum()`.

If this gives you a value close to zero then it means that your rectangle in the image is black.

Normally it won't be exactly 0 as there will be some signal, so you might want to find a good threshold that works for your setup based on the illumination, so your conditional can be:

```
if im[row_min:row_max, col_min:col_max, :].reshape(-1).sum() <= threshold
    # do something here, the rectangle area is black
```

Using your code:

```
import cv2
#from gpiozero import LED

print("packege Imported")

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1)
cap.set(3, 640)
cap.set(4, 480)

font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX

IM_WIDTH = 640
IM_HEIGHT = 480

TL_Zone1 = (int(IM_WIDTH*0.2),int(IM_HEIGHT*0.4))
BR_Zone1 = (int(IM_WIDTH*0.3),int(IM_HEIGHT*0.6))

xmin, ymin = TL_Zone1
xmax, ymax = BR_Zone1

#led1 = LED(2)


def colorDetection(img, max_black_value=0.1, max_black_cover=0.2):
    
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)[ymin:ymax, xmin:xmax]
    
    # relative amount of pixels with value less than max_black_value in rectangle
    black_cover = gray[gray <= max_black_value].size / gray.size
    
    if black_cover >= max_black_cover:
        cv2.putText(img, "color detected",(TL_Zone1[0] + 10, TL_Zone1[1] - 10), font, 1, (0, 0, 255), 3, cv2.LINE_AA)
        #led1.on()
    else:
        cv2.putText(img, "color not detected",(TL_Zone1[0] + 10, TL_Zone1[1] - 10), font, 1, (0, 0, 255), 3, cv2.LINE_AA)
        #led1.off()


while True:
    success, img = cap.read()
    imgDetection = img.copy()
    
    # pixels with gray value less than 0.1 will be considered black
    max_black_value = 0.1 
    
    # if the rectangle has more than 20% of pixels detected as black
    # then the if statement will be true
    max_black_cover = 0.2 
    
    colorDetection(imgDetection, max_black_value, max_black_cover)

    cv2.rectangle(imgDetection, TL_Zone1, BR_Zone1, (0, 0, 255), 8)

    cv2.imshow("Video", img)
    cv2.imshow("Detection", imgDetection)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
```

Comment: First of all, thank you for the feedback. I have adapted the question with the code and incorporated your feedback. I just don't have the code fully working yet I think. Would you like to help me with that because then I am very grateful to you.

Comment: @Thimo Try the modified example

Comment: Thank you for editing my code because it looks better. Unfortunately it always says "color detected". I've added a few samples to my question to show you how I test it. When there is a small black dot in the area, the color should be detected and if it only sees the white paper, it should not.

Comment: @Thimo the if statement was always true unless the full rectangle was black. I added some values that you can customize to tune your system. For example you can set a tolerance on the black value. You can assume that pixels with 0.1 value will be almost black so they should be detected.
Then you can set what is the minimum amount of the rectangle that should be black, for example if you set max_black_cover to 0.5 than it means that the detection will occur only if the rectangle is at least covered by 50% in black

Comment: I am really happy with your sugesstie and I think the last code is exactly what I want. That if you have an area that is about 5% black that the color has been detected. I did test your code and did not get it working unfortunately. 
I only got the color detected when all of the capture is black. So not when only the zone is completely black. I also found that it only detected the color in very black and when I adjusted it I had no idea that it was adjusted. Do you know how to solved this?

Comment: You need to consider the following: the color black corresponds to 0 intensity. however in the real world, your camera will detect some light depending on the black you are using and the illumination, so you need to identify what is the threshold level for your black value. Try to increase `max_black_value`. Play around with the values, insert some print statements to check what are the values you are getting. I do not have your setup and cannot know what values you get, therefore i cannot debug the code for your specific case. If the answer helped you, please consider accepting it.